# Ошибка вывода стэка

Tags: java

Толи я дурак, то ли лыжи не едут!Написал программку по примеру из книжки,а она работает не так как я хочу.Подскажите в чём злой умысел?
[Вот код](http://ideone.com/8EMhFp)

Программа выводит:

СТЕК в mystack1:
4

CТЕК в mystack2:
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0

Вопрос:почему не выводит 3 2 1 0 для mystack1?

Comment: `public int stck[];` :D

`public man stck = 'http://hashcode.ru/users/2092/stck';` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В блоке кода:

```
   System.out.println("CTEK B mystack1: ");
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++);
      System.out.println(mystack1.pop());
```

уберите точку с запятой в строке:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++);
```

Приучайтесь сразу писать циклы в виде:

```
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
      System.out.println(mystack1.pop());
   }
```

Comment: Всё таки это я дурак((А лыжи ехали!Спасибо